# How to set color different in plotly express based on conditions

Tags: colors, bar-chart, plotly-python

I plotted a stacked bar, and want to set the Apr_max set the first column color (green, for example) different than other (RED).

Current my code is:

```
fig_page2 = px.bar(data_frame=df_raw,
                 x='Company', y=['Apr_Min', 'Apr_Max'],
                 barmode="stack", labels={'variable': ' ', 'value':'Number'},
                 color_discrete_sequence=['rgb(233,233,233)', 'rgb(255,69,0)'],
                 width=1000, height=400).update_layout(autosize=True,
                                                       title={
                                                            'text': "APR Comparison", 'y':0.9,'x':0.5,
                                                            'xanchor': 'center',
                                                            'yanchor': 'middle'},
                                                       yaxis=dict(title='APR Range', tickformat=',.0%', range=[0,1]),
                                                       paper_bgcolor='rgb(233,233,233)',
                                                       plot_bgcolor='rgb(233,233,233)',
                                                       showlegend=False)
```

And here is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IINhU.jpg)

How can I make the highlighted bar as green, while keep rest of colors?

ps: my dataset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg72v.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

- create data frame to match structure of your data frame (Note your image missed the *Company* column)
- create figure exactly as you have (just formatted code)
- update figure to change **marker_color** of *Apr_Max* trace to be a **list** instead of string.  First column *green*, all other columns color that was assigned in creation of figure

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df_raw = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Apr_Min": np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.3, 10),
        "Apr_Max": np.random.uniform(0.3, 0.7, 10),
        "Company": list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR")[0:10],
    }
)

fig_page2 = px.bar(
    data_frame=df_raw,
    x="Company",
    y=["Apr_Min", "Apr_Max"],
    barmode="stack",
    labels={"variable": " ", "value": "Number"},
    color_discrete_sequence=["rgb(233,233,233)", "rgb(255,69,0)"],
    width=1000,
    height=400,
).update_layout(
    autosize=True,
    title={
        "text": "APR Comparison",
        "y": 0.9,
        "x": 0.5,
        "xanchor": "center",
        "yanchor": "middle",
    },
    yaxis=dict(title="APR Range", tickformat=",.0%", range=[0, 1]),
    paper_bgcolor="rgb(233,233,233)",
    plot_bgcolor="rgb(233,233,233)",
    showlegend=False,
)

# want different color for first bar... change marker color to a list for appropriate trace
fig_page2.for_each_trace(
    lambda t: t.update(
        {
            "marker": {
                "color": [
                    "green" if i == 0 else t.marker.color for i, _ in enumerate(t.x)
                ]
            }
        }
    )
    if t.name == "Apr_Max"
    else t
)
```

[image]